# Refreshing page resets inputs - is it possible to avoid this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, controller

I am using MVC 4 and the MVC Futures `[Serializable]` feature to persist data through a multi-step wizard. The wizard itself is just collecting info from the user and then generating an automated response based on those inputs. I have no need to permanently store the inputs into a DB.

Now, I've run into a bit of a problem that I can handle on the Confirm page of the wizard, but I am wondering if I can obviate the need to do that. My problem is that if a user hits "Refresh/F5" (and you know they will) all their inputs on a particular step and all prior steps are erased. If they are on the final step before confirmation they will not realize they have cleared everything they input on prior steps. The way to handle that is to put a validation summary on the confirmation page which will then show that every input needs to be redone. This presents a problem because it destroys the user experience (they have to go back through all the steps and re-input).

Here is a sample of my controller code:

```
//This is the serialization:
private MyData myData;
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var serialized = Request.Form["myData"];
        if (serialized != null) //Form was posted containing serialized data
        {
            myData = (MyData)new MvcSerializer().Deserialize(serialized, SerializationMode.Signed);
            TryUpdateModel(myData);
        }
        else
            myData = (MyData)TempData["myData"] ?? new MyData();
    }
    protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
            TempData["myData"] = myData;
    }
...
//This shows a mid-step in the wizard - only as an example:
public ActionResult Step2(string backButton, string nextButton)
{
    if (backButton != null)
        return RedirectToAction("Step1");
    else if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Step3");
    else
        return View("Step2", myData);
```

I have been researching most yesterday and this morning on various things related to `[Serializable]`, `TempData`, `Session`, `OutputCache` and the like, including refreshing a page and persisting data but cannot find anything on point.

The only thing that made sense was in the `return` call, which occurs after everything in a particular `ActionResult`. I don't know if that's on point, but it makes sense that a page refresh would cause all the data entered to disappear in this situation because the model is not being hit until the end. But if that's the problem I cannot figure out how to solve it without breaking the code I already have.

I appreciate any guidance.

P.S. There is no tag for MVC 4 so I just chose MVC and MVC 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's with TempData. Data stored inside survives only for a single request which in your case is the redirect.

The first possibility is to keep the data for longer in TempData:

```
...
else
{
    myData = (MyData)TempData["myData"] ?? new MyData();
    TempData.Keep();
}
```

which kinda more assimilates it to Session. So you could use Session instead of TempData.

Another solution is to store the data on each step in some temporary table in your database so that you can retrieve it on each step. I guess you have this problem on every step, not only at the last one to show the summary. Anyway if you are only concerned about the last step why not persist the data into the database anyway?

Comment: That worked. Curious, I tried putting it in the OnResultExecuted and it works as well. The short answer to your last question: I am not a programmer. The long answer: I only need it through the steps, at which point the end result is an auto response to the user based on their selections (whether its a calculated total for something, or a generic evaluation of their situation). I am looking to persist data in other scenarios, just not for this one.